# Show: $\int f \, d\nu = \int f \, d\mu$ for continuous $f$ implies $\nu=\mu$

Tags: measure-theory

Consider two $\sigma$-finite measures $\mu$ and $\nu$, both defined on $(\mathbb{R}^{k},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^{k}))$. Prove that if $\int{f}d\mu=\int{f}d \nu$ for all continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R}^{k}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then $\mu=\nu$. Can someone give me hints?

Comment: For each open box $A$ consider a sequence of continuous functions $f_n$ that are equal to $1$ on a box $B_n\subset A$ and zero outside the box $A$, with $B_n$ growing to $A$ as $n$ growths. Use the equality of their integrals and take the limit.This gives you that the measures of $A$ are the same. *I changed the way the boxes change from my previous comment to be able to use monotone convergence, since dominated convergence is not guaranteed to be applicable*.

Comment: Once you know they are equal on open boxes, they are equal on open sets, since open sets are the union of all the open boxes they contain.This is again using dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: @ ABC: I might be wrong, but once you know that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are equal on open boxes, then you are done. This is because the collection of open boxes is a $\pi$-system which generates $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Unless maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. For a closed set $F \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$, define $$f_n (x) := \max\{1-n d(x,F),0\}.$$ Show that $f_n \downarrow 1_F$ and that $f_n$ is continuous and bounded.
2. Conclude from the assumption and the monotone convergence theorem that $$\mu(F) = \nu(F) \qquad \text{for all closed sets $F$.}$$
3. Deduce that $\mu(A) = \nu(A)$ for any Borel set $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^k)$.

**Remark:** Note that it suffices to assume $$\int f \, d\mu = \int f \, d\nu$$ for all **bounded**  continuous functions $f$.

Comment: I have difficulty to get step 3. Can you provide more details?

Comment: @Ben 1. Recall that the Borel-sigma-algebra is generated by the closed sets. 2. Do you know any uniqueness theorem for measures?

Comment: For 2. Do you mean if the measures are same for $\pi$ system, then they are same for the sigma-algebra generated by that $\pi$ system?

Comment: @Ben Yes, exactly.

Comment: I am not sure I am right or not: for $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^{k})$, what should I do? Just take $F\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{k}$? And do it again?

Comment: @Ben Use $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^k) = \sigma(F; F \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k \, \text{closed}\}$.

Comment: Do I need to use induction here?

Comment: @Ben Induction? No. Step 1+2 show that for $\mathcal{D} := \{F; F \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k \, \text{closed}\}$ we have $$\nu(F) = \mu(F)$$ for all $F \in \mathcal{D}$. Since $\mathcal{D}$ is a $\pi$-system which generates $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^k)$, the claim follows directly from the already-mentioned result on uniqueness of measures.

Comment: But in step 1, you choose $F\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ not $\mathbb{R}^{k}$?

Comment: @Ben Typo, sorry.

Comment: The theorem about equivalence of two measures needs $\mu$ and $\nu$ are sigma finite on $\mathscr{D}$. But we only have they are sigma finite on $(\mathbb{R}^{k},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^{k}))$.

Comment: @Ben So what? $\mu$ and $\nu$ *are* measures on $(\mathbb{R}^k,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^k))$.

Comment: In the proof of equivalence of two measures, we need "there exists $B_{i}\in\mathscr{D}$ with $\nu(B_i)=\mu(B_i)<\infty$ and $\mathbb{R}^{k}=\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}B_i$". You can see it #13.http://www.randomservices.org/random/prob/Existence.html

Comment: @Ben Use that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are $\sigma$-finite. (Sorry, couldn't answer your comment earlier.)